# I want to show chat history in react-native gifted chat

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native gifted chat module
My requirement is that i want to show chat history 
And for chat history i'm using API which fetches the 10 message record through server.
Now my chat is working fine But, i'm unable to show my chat history messages
What's possible solution for that
Note : I'm aware of using "Load Earlier function in gifted chat"

My code :

```
    render() {

            return (

                    <GiftedChat
                      messages={this.state.messages}
                      onSend={(messages) => this.onSend(messages)}
                      user={{username}}
                      onKeyPress={this.typing}
                      value={this.state.messages}
                  onChangeText={ (messages) => this.setState({messages}) }
                  onLoadEarlier={this.onLoadEarlier}
                  isLoadingEarlier={this.state.isLoadingEarlier}
                      />


            );
        }

// This is my API FOR CHAT HISTORY
     getChat() {
            console.log("navnit jha "+this.state.groupId);
            fetch('http://35.154.169.9:4130/baduga/'+groupId+'/getChat', {method: "GET"})
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                var Data = [];
                if (responseData!==null) {
                    console.log("navnit"+JSON.stringify(responseData));
                    for(var i=0;i<responseData.length;i++){
                        Data.push({
                            msg:responseData[i].msg,
                            username:responseData[i].username
                        });
                    }
                    console.log("chat called "+JSON.stringify(Data));
                    this.setState({dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(Data)});
                }
            })
            .done();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

@baduga biz, your "Load Earlier" button is showing?

In your code is missing the 'loadEarlier' props.

```
<GiftedChat
  messages={this.state.messages}
  onSend={(messages) => this.onSend(messages)}
  user={{username}}
  onKeyPress={this.typing}
  value={this.state.messages}
  onChangeText={ (messages) => this.setState({messages}) }
  loadEarlier={true} // this was missing
  onLoadEarlier={this.onLoadEarlier}
  isLoadingEarlier={this.state.isLoadingEarlier}
/>
```